# FreeCAD environment installed with Conda does not work in VSCode/ Pylance?

Tags: python, conda, libraries, environment, freecad

I installed the [FreeCAD conda environment](https://wiki.freecad.org/Conda) hoping that it would provide code complete to help me write a macro. However the imports only work if I include:

```py
import freecad
```

before

```py
import FreeCAD
import Fem
```

along with this VSCode does not provide code complete for Fem, Mesh and other libraries even though their imports do not throw errors when I run the code, I'm pretty sure I have chosen the environment in VSCode correctly so I am unsure why these errors occur.